# константы и переменные в tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

опция prefer-const в настройках tslint. по умолчанию это правило говорит, если переменная используется один раз, то она должна быть объявлена как const, а если больше одного, то как let:

```
function foo(data: number[]) {
    const ln: number = data.length;
    for (let i: number = 0; i < ln; ++i) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}

foo([1, 2, 3]);
foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

в моем понимании константа это постоянное *на протяжении выполнения всей программы*. а тут каждый раз выполняя функцию, мы получаем разную длинну (ln). да, она константа, но она константа *на время выполнения функции*. не говно код ли это? может просто у меня не правильное понимание о константах.. в обычном js я бы написал var и не парился бы.

или например когда мы объявляем массив, а потом добавляем туда данные. разве это константа? а tslint ругается, если я поставлю let

```
function foo(): number[] {
    const myArray: number[] = [];

    myArray.push(1);
    myArray.push(2);
    myArray.push(3);

    return myArray;
}
```

еще я заметил интересную вещь. если массив объявляется через let внутри функции (пример выше), то tslint ругается. а если без функции, то нет

```
let myArray: number[] = [];

myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
```

когда и как использовать константы в typescript вместе с tslint?

Comment: Он ругаеться потому что внутри функции своя область видимости

Comment: можно подробней? в чем разница в области видимости? я определил глобально, но использую то переменную "на чтение", а не на переопределение переменной. поэтому он я так понял должен ругнуться